# Column count doesn't match value count at row

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO clnt_reports_01 (r_id, cl_no, cl_no, servi, size, vol, 
deliver_point, port_, a_port, road, term, compet, speed, 
rcomments, stage, meetrating, username, user_status, kids, 
hobbies, comments)

VALUES (1, 123123, "test", "test", "test", "test", 
"test", "test", "test", "test", 1, "test", "test",
 3, 5, "test", "test", 5, "test", "test");
```

Getting the error -

> Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row

Comment: VALUES (1, 123123, 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 1, 'test', 'test', 3, 5, 'test', 'test', 5, 'test', 'test'); Like so? Still getting the same error. @lad2025

Comment: count the field names and then count the values..

Comment: 21 column in INSERT, 20 column is VALUES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You have specified 21 columns and provided only 20 values so there is a mismatch.

`cl_no` seems to be repeated twice. Remove that.

---

You need to use single quotes instead of double for text

```
INSERT INTO clnt_reports_01 ( 
r_id,
cl_no,
servi,
size,
vol,
deliver_point,
port_,
a_port,
road,
term,
compet,
speed,
rcomments,
stage,
meetrating,
username,
user_status,
kids,
hobbies,
comments)

VALUES (1, 
123123, 
'test', 
'test', 
'test', 
'test', 
'test', 
'test', 
'test', 
'test', 
1, 
'test', 
'test', 
3, 
5,
'test', 
'test', 
5, 
'test', 
'test');
```

Answer (score 4):

Qoute strings with `'` and **make sure there is the same number of column in both cases (20)**:

```
INSERT INTO clnt_reports_01 (r_id,cl_no,servi,size,vol,deliver_point,port_,a_port,road,term,compet,speed,rcomments,stage,meetrating,username,user_status,kids,hobbies,comments)

VALUES (1, 123123, 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 1, 'test', 'test', 3, 5, 'test', 'test', 5, 'test', 'test');
```

`"` is treated as identifier (column name).

Also better use `INSERT ... SELECT` for readability:

```
INSERT INTO clnt_reports_01 (
  r_id,
  cl_no,
  servi,
  size,
  vol,
  deliver_point,
  port_,
  a_port,
  road,
  term,
  compet,
  speed,
  rcomments,
  stage,
  meetrating,
  username,
  user_status,
  kids,
  hobbies,
  comments)
SELECT
  1       AS r_id,
 123123   AS cl_no,
 'test'   AS servi,
 'test'   AS size,
 'test'   As vol, 
 'test'   AS deliver_point,
 'test'   AS port_,
 'test'   AS a_port,
 'test'   AS road,
 'test'   AS term,
  1       AS compet,
 'test'   AS speed,
 'test'   AS rcomments,
  3       AS stage,
  5       AS meetrating,
 'test'   AS username,
 'test'   AS user_status,
  5       AS kids,
 'test'   AS hobbies,
 'test'   AS comments;
```

Comment: mysql is fine with double quotes see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36100/1)

Comment: @amdixon It depends on [ANSI_QOUTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes)

Comment: ok, but the error message is quite clear about a count difference in this case

Comment: @amdixon No author change question

Comment: @rapidvaters See my updated answer and INSERT SELECT

Answer (score 2):

Insert query to specify 21 columns and passing value 20.

Answer (score 1):

You are providing 20 values for 21 columns, maybe because you've listed the column `cl_no` twice. Even if you fix the column/value count issue, you'll get this error

> Error Code : 1136
>
> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 0):

well, your column count (21) does not match your value count (20) , you're trying to insert 20 things into 21 columns....

This is given away by the error that says

> Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row

Answer (score 0):

For this problem :

> Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row

`cl_no` used twice, remove one this column.

You can use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Such as :

`"test" -> 'test'`

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO fgm_pastor(
matriculePastor,
pastorName,
pastorSurname,
pastorBirthdayDate,
birthdayPlace,
pastorFathername,
pastorMothername,
pastorSexe,
pastorPhone,
pastorEmail,
dateConversion,
workBeforeBibleSchool,
rankProbation,
areaOfCalling,
nberYearArea,
nbreYearDistrict,
martialSituation,
nationality,
pastorAdresse,
photoProfil,
raisonIndispoMissionnaire,
id) 
VALUES
(
'matriculetest3',
'nom test',
'prenomtest',
'2013-09-12',
'Dagobert',
'mon pere resr' ,
'ma mere test',
'M',
'phone test',
'pastorEmail test',
'2018-12-28',
'infomaticien',
'rank test',
'area test',
1,
3,
'Single test',
'Cameroun test',
'adresse test',
'phototest'
'RAS',
4
);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it